# Zend sanitizing input

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I've sanitized my form's input (textarea field) and when I display it on my view it comes out like this:

&lt;p&gt;I\'m in it to win it!! I\'m looking forward to playing the contest in &lt;br /&gt;Contest Central. He aims to cross-pollinate the stage, screen and stereo &lt;br /&gt;with work that speaks to both the humor and frustrations of modern life.&lt;/p&gt;

In my controller I have this:

```
public function init(){

 $this->view->setEscape('html_entity_decode');
 $this->view->setEscape('stripslashes');

}
```

But only one works, if I erase one the setEscape then the other works and vice versa. So I can get stripslashes to work if I put it first but html_entity_decode wont work and vice versa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define your own function that should be used for escaping. For example, you can defined a class My_Tools in library/My/Tools.php as follows:

```
<?php
#Tools.php

class My_Tools {

    /**
     * My custom escape function
     *
     * @param string $str String to be escaped
     * @return string Escaped string
     */
    static function myEscape($str) {
        $str = html_entity_decode($str);
        return stripslashes($str);
    }

}

?>
```

Then, your init() could have the following form:

```
public function init() {

    require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/My/Tools.php');
    $this->view->setEscape(array('My_Tools', 'myEscape'));

}
```

Off course it would be better to add Tools to Autoloader, but for this is just an example.

Comment: In myEscape function what $str am I passing as a parameter?

Comment: @coder3. ZF will automatically pass your a string that you want to escape to myEscape. So you use escape method in a view as usually, i.e. echo $this->escape('string to be escaped').

Comment: Awesome! thanks a lot!! Can I give you credit here or is there like a point system?

Comment: @coder3. Glad I could help. If you could upvote my answer it would be nice.